# Error in "Trigger Now" for Data flow activity as "InternalServerError executing request"

Tags: azure

Error in "Trigger Now" for Data flow activity as "InternalServerError executing request" but it is working on Debug mode...i checked the file there is no issue in that.

we are processing the files from blob to azure synapse datawarehouse but when i trigger the pipeline in debug mode it is working but we are getting error in triggerNow.